# Problemas con JRLoader de JasperReport en Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jasper-reports, ireport, hql

Estoy aprendiendo a hacer reportes y lo estoy aplicando a una Aplicación de Gestión con Hibernate que estoy realizando.
He seguido varios tutoriales pero me da un error en el JRLoader.

Primero cree una clase java para los reportes:

```
public class ReportePresupuesto {
private int presupuestoId;
private String presupuestoNombre;
private String nombreCliente;
private String dniCifCliente;
private String direccionCliente;
private int telefonoCliente;
private String concepto;
private double precio;
private int cantidad;
private double subtotal;
private double total;
private double iva;
private double totalIva;

public ReportePresupuesto() {
}

public ReportePresupuesto(int presupuestoId, String presupuestoNombre, String nombreCliente, String dniCifCliente, String direccionCliente, int telefonoCliente, String concepto, double precio, int cantidad, double subtotal, double total, double iva, double totalIva) {
    this.presupuestoId = presupuestoId;
    this.presupuestoNombre = presupuestoNombre;
    this.nombreCliente = nombreCliente;
    this.dniCifCliente = dniCifCliente;
    this.direccionCliente = direccionCliente;
    this.telefonoCliente = telefonoCliente;
    this.concepto = concepto;
    this.precio = precio;
    this.cantidad = cantidad;
    this.subtotal = subtotal;
    this.total = total;
    this.iva = iva;
    this.totalIva = totalIva;
}
 public ReportePresupuesto(int presupuestoId, String presupuestoNombre, String nombreCliente, String dniCifCliente, String direccionCliente, int telefonoCliente, double total, double iva, double totalIva) {
    this.presupuestoId = presupuestoId;
    this.presupuestoNombre = presupuestoNombre;
    this.nombreCliente = nombreCliente;
    this.dniCifCliente = dniCifCliente;
    this.direccionCliente = direccionCliente;
    this.telefonoCliente = telefonoCliente;
    this.total = total;
    this.iva = iva;
    this.totalIva = totalIva;
}

  public ReportePresupuesto(String concepto, double precio, int cantidad, double subtotal) {
    this.concepto = concepto;
    this.precio = precio;
    this.cantidad = cantidad;
    this.subtotal = subtotal;
}


public int getPresupuestoId() {
    return presupuestoId;
}

public void setPresupuestoId(int presupuestoId) {
    this.presupuestoId = presupuestoId;
}

public String getPresupuestoNombre() {
    return presupuestoNombre;
}

public void setPresupuestoNombre(String presupuestoNombre) {
    this.presupuestoNombre = presupuestoNombre;
}

public String getNombreCliente() {
    return nombreCliente;
}

public void setNombreCliente(String nombreCliente) {
    this.nombreCliente = nombreCliente;
}

public String getDniCifCliente() {
    return dniCifCliente;
}

public void setDniCifCliente(String dniCifCliente) {
    this.dniCifCliente = dniCifCliente;
}

public String getDireccionCliente() {
    return direccionCliente;
}

public void setDireccionCliente(String direccionCliente) {
    this.direccionCliente = direccionCliente;
}

public int getTelefonoCliente() {
    return telefonoCliente;
}

public void setTelefonoCliente(int telefonoCliente) {
    this.telefonoCliente = telefonoCliente;
}

public String getConcepto() {
    return concepto;
}

public void setConcepto(String concepto) {
    this.concepto = concepto;
}

public double getPrecio() {
    return precio;
}

public void setPrecio(double precio) {
    this.precio = precio;
}

public int getCantidad() {
    return cantidad;
}

public void setCantidad(int cantidad) {
    this.cantidad = cantidad;
}

public double getSubtotal() {
    return subtotal;
}

public void setSubtotal(double subtotal) {
    this.subtotal = subtotal;
}

public double getTotal() {
    return total;
}

public void setTotal(double total) {
    this.total = total;
}

public double getIva() {
    return iva;
}

public void setIva(double iva) {
    this.iva = iva;
}

public double getTotalIva() {
    return totalIva;
}

public void setTotalIva(double totalIva) {
    this.totalIva = totalIva;
}
```

Generé varios constructores: algunos piden los datos que formarán la tabla del reporte (como el concepto, la cantidad, el precio y los subtotales)y otros los datos que se introducirán solo una vez (como el nombre del cliente o el número del presupuesto)

Después utilice el nombre de cada atributo de la clase java de reportes para crear los Fields del Reporte.jrxml y lo compilé en el Reporte.jasper
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Dentro de mi código del Jframe en el botón imprimir introduje el siguiente código:

```
List lista = new ArrayList();
    String clienteNombre = (String) cmb_cre_pre_cli.getSelectedItem();
    String concepto = txt_cre_pre_con.getText();

    OperarClientes opeCli = new OperarClientes();
    OperarLineaPresMaterial opeLinMat = new OperarLineaPresMaterial();
    OperarLineaPresTrabajo opeLinTra = new OperarLineaPresTrabajo();
    OperarPresupuestos opePre = new OperarPresupuestos();

    List<Cliente> clientes = opeCli.buscarClientePorNombre(clienteNombre);
    Cliente cliente = new Cliente();
    for(int x=0;x<clientes.size();x++){
        cliente.setClienteId(clientes.get(x).getClienteId());
        cliente.setClienteNombre(clientes.get(x).getClienteNombre());
        cliente.setDniCif(clientes.get(x).getDniCif());
        cliente.setClienteDireccion(clientes.get(x).getClienteDireccion());
        cliente.setClienteTelefono(clientes.get(x).getClienteTelefono());
    }

    int clienteId = opeCli.buscarClienteIdPorNombre(clienteNombre);
    List<Presupuesto> presupuestos = opePre.buscarPresupuesto(clienteId, concepto);
    Presupuesto presupuesto = new Presupuesto();
    for(int x=0; x<presupuestos.size();x++){
        presupuesto.setPresupuestoId(presupuestos.get(x).getPresupuestoId());
        presupuesto.setCliente(presupuestos.get(x).getCliente());
        presupuesto.setPresupuestoTrabajo(presupuestos.get(x).getPresupuestoTrabajo());
        presupuesto.setPresupuestoTotal(presupuestos.get(x).getPresupuestoTotal());
    }
    double total = presupuesto.getPresupuestoTotal();
    double iva = (total*21)/100;
    double totalIva = total + iva;
    ReportePresupuesto reporte1 = new ReportePresupuesto(presupuesto.getPresupuestoId(), presupuesto.getPresupuestoTrabajo(), cliente.getClienteNombre(), cliente.getDniCif(), cliente.getClienteDireccion(),cliente.getClienteTelefono(), total, iva, totalIva);
    lista.add(reporte1);

    List<LineaPresMaterial> lineasMat = opeLinMat.buscarLinea(presupuesto);
    for(Object o : lineasMat){
        LineaPresMaterial linea = (LineaPresMaterial) o;
        ReportePresupuesto reporte = new ReportePresupuesto(linea.getConcepto(),linea.getPrecio(), linea.getCantidad(), linea.getSubtotal());
        lista.add(reporte);
    }

    List<LineaPresTrabajo> lineasTra = opeLinTra.buscarLinea(presupuesto);
    for(Object o : lineasTra){
        LineaPresTrabajo linea = (LineaPresTrabajo) o;
        ReportePresupuesto reporte = new ReportePresupuesto(linea.getConcepto(),linea.getPrecio(), linea.getCantidad(), linea.getTotalLinea());
        lista.add(reporte);
    }

    try{
        JasperReport reporte = (JasperReport) JRLoader.loadObject(ClassLoader.getSystemResource("src\\Reportes\\ReportePresupuesto.jasper"));
        JasperPrint  print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(reporte, null, new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(lista));
        JasperViewer view = new JasperViewer(print, false);
        view.setVisible(true);
        view.setTitle("Presupuesto:");
    }catch(JRException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Con la aplicación en funcionamiento al pulsar el botón Imprimir, me genera el siguiente error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRLoader.loadObject(JRLoader.java:183)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRLoader.loadObject(JRLoader.java:167)
at Vista.Presupuestos.CrearPresupuesto.btm_cre_pre_impActionPerformed(CrearPresupuesto.java:609)
at Vista.Presupuestos.CrearPresupuesto.access$200(CrearPresupuesto.java:44)
at Vista.Presupuestos.CrearPresupuesto$3.actionPerformed(CrearPresupuesto.java:164)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6533)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6298)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:90)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Os adjunto además una captura de las librerías que he incluido para usar Jasper Report(además de plugin de iReport)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sin nada más, muchas gracias de antemano y a ver si pudierais ayudarme.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Por lo que puedo ver en la traza del log. Deberías buscar alguna referencia a un componente de tu ventana que podría estar quedándose sin un valor asignado.

Intenta revisar estas líneas que corresponden a una clase que has creado.

```
at Vista.Presupuestos.CrearPresupuesto.btm_cre_pre_impActionPerformed(CrearPresupuesto.java:609)
at Vista.Presupuestos.CrearPresupuesto.access$200(CrearPresupuesto.java:44)
at Vista.Presupuestos.CrearPresupuesto$3.actionPerformed(CrearPresupuesto.java:164)
```

Revisa las líneas 609, 44 y 164 y verifica las variables y/u objetos que estás referenciando.

Comment: Buenas. He debugeado y cambiado algunas variables por si acaso.
He mirado no fuera a ser que me estuviera dando error al crear los objetos ReportePresupuesto, como había generado algunos constructores omitiendo variables en los parametros, he construido un objeto completo para probar, pero el fallo me lo genera siempre al llegar a esta linea:
`JasperReport reporte = (JasperReport) JRLoader.loadObject(ClassLoader.getSystemResource("src\\Reportes\\ReportePresupuesto.jasper"));`

Answer (score 0):

Me faltaban varias librerías, actualicé la de jasperreports javaflow a una superior y me dejó utilizar `JRLoader. LoadObject(new File (“src/Reportes/ReportePresupuesto“)`.

Después agregué la libreria joda-time y servlet-api para salvar otro error que me daba.

Ahora mismo me está dando un error en el fillManager y es por tipo de datos. 
Estoy intentando averiguar como cambiar el tipo de dato de los Field de ReportePresupuesto.jrxml, puesto que lo cambio en el código y no sé por qué, vuelve al tipo por defecto.

RESUELTO. Una vez cambiados los tipos de datos de los campos le dí a Preview en el editor del ReportePresupuesto.jrxml, ahora me funciona dentro del Netbeans.