# JasperReport no funciona una vez compilado el programa

Tags: java, hibernate, jasper-reports

Alguien sabe por qué JasperReport me funciona al ejecutar el programa en Netbeans pero después no funciona con el programa compilado?

El programa que he desarrollado y donde aplicó el JasperReport es este:
[Problemas con JRLoader de JasperReport en Hibernate](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/284582/problemas-con-jrloader-de-jasperreport-en-hibernate/284663#284663)

Comment: ¿Qué errores te da? Puede ser porque usas rutas relativas/absolutas y al compilar/empaquetar estas referencias se pierden. Pero primero tienes que decir qué errores tienes.

Answer (score 0):

es por la ruta.
He creado esto y funciona, pero estoy intentando acceder a la ruta relativa, para no cargar mucho el programa.

```
File file = new File("src\\Reportes\\ReportePresupuesto.jasper");


    if(file.exists()){
        try{
            JasperReport reporte = (JasperReport) JRLoader.loadObject(file);//(getClass().getResource("Reportes\\ReportePresupuesto.jasper"));;//JasperCompileManager.compileReport("src/Reportes/ReportePresupuesto.jrxml");
            JasperPrint  print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(reporte, null, new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(lista));
            JasperViewer view = new JasperViewer(print, false);
            view.setVisible(true);
            view.setTitle("Guardar Presupuesto:");
        }catch(JRException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }else{
        File file2 = new File("ReportePresupuesto.jasper");
        try{
            JasperReport reporte = (JasperReport) JRLoader.loadObject(file2);//(getClass().getResource("Reportes\\ReportePresupuesto.jasper"));;//JasperCompileManager.compileReport("src/Reportes/ReportePresupuesto.jrxml");
            JasperPrint  print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(reporte, null, new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(lista));
            JasperViewer view = new JasperViewer(print, false);
            view.setVisible(true);
            view.setTitle("Guardar Presupuesto:");
        }catch(JRException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Así funciona pero me obliga a sacar los .jasper a la carpeta dist
y no quiero que quede así, estoy probando rutas dentro del .jar para por lo menos evitar tener que copiar estos archivos
gracias!